# Best Mercurial (Hg) GUI for CentOS?

Tags: user-interface, mercurial, centos5

Does anyone have any recommendations for a Mercurial GUI in CentOS 5.6?

I tried installing TortoiseHg but the installation failed requiring new packages. I am just looking for a tool that works decently. Will appreciate comments based off prior experience.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the new package requirements? TortoiseHG is supposed to work, and if you rephrase the question in regards to getting the installation to work, maybe it won't get closed.

Comment: There is a link as to how TortoiseHg can be made to work with CentOS5.6: http://groups.google.com/group/thg-dev/browse_thread/thread/a51e8f371aebc90b  but I can't make these changes to the system. I am not interested in TortoiseHG anymore; I'm just interested in some GUI tool that works on Centos 5.6.

Comment: That thread seems to detail changes to TorgoiseHG itself that are already part of 2.0.4, the latest release. Doesn't say much about the packages. It's unfortunate that you seem to have given up on TortoiseHG, it's the best one.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/OtherTools) contains a list of GUI tools for Mercurial. That's about all I can give you.

Comment: Thanks, I did have the list but had trouble with some tools; was hoping with someone with prior experience. Currently, the Eclipse Hg plugin is what I've found works best for me so far.